# How to observe navigation controller in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I have a loading view controller as launcher view controller.

I want to send NSNotification only after loading view controller (which has no Navigation controller) pushed to main view controller.

How should I observe that in appDelegate and call my method only when main view controller became active?

Comment: What does this have to do with push notifications? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Wain Edited my questions, I want to do this in appDelegate - onRemoteNotificationRecieved